# dbms_debug in development environment

Tags: oracle, security, oracle11g, database-administration

My question is this:  Are there any security issues that should caution and limit my use of `DBMS_DEBUG` in my DEVELOPMENT environment due to the permissions I need in order to run in debug (again, NOT production)?

I would like to use DBMS_DEBUG from Toad on my DEVELOPMENT oracle database.  This is NOT on my PRODUCTION environment.  I believe this will require the following permissions:

1. `GRANT ALTER SESSION TO cfi;`
2. `GRANT CREATE SESSION TO cfi;`
3. `GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_DEBUG to cfi;`
4. `GRANT DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE TO cfi;`
5. `GRANT DEBUG CONNECT SESSION TO cfi;`

Is granting these permissions to my schema in DEV ONLY a security risk?

Comment: I can't see any reason why not to grant those on a development environment. Especially if that server is only used for that specific project

Comment: Hi and thank you for your input.  "cfi" is the schema that needs to run dbms_debug.  The database is only used for development but its used for other projects.  But cfi does not have execute permissions for any of the procedures owned by other schemas.  So there is no security issue associated with adding these 5 permissions to the other existing permissions currently granted to "cfi" . . .right?